# How to compile wine

Tags: 12.04, wine, compiling

I am a Wine PPA user for [Scott Ritchie](https://launchpad.net/~scottritchie) for several years and have loved that PPA but I want to start compiling Wine for testing purposes in another PC with Ubuntu.

So I have a couple of questions regarding this:

What special flags or steps are needed to compile Wine on Ubuntu?

How to include the pulseaudio code to Wine to solve any sound issues in the process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No special flags are needed, really. Audio is supported out-of-the-box.

---

Here are the commands you'll need to run to get Wine up and running, straight from the source.

```
sudo -s
cd /tmp
wget http://winezeug.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/install-wine-deps.sh
sh install-wine-deps.sh
wget http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/wine/source/1.5/wine-1.5.9.tar.bz2
tar xjvf wine-1.5.9.tar.bz2
cd wine-1.5.9/
./configure
make
make install
```

---

Here's what the commands actually do:

> - Drop to a root shell
> - Go to the temp folder
> - Download the Wine dependency installer script
> - Run the Wine dependency installer script
> - Download the Wine source
> - Extract the Wine source
> - Enter the Wine source directory
> - Run the configuration script
> - Compile Wine
> - Install Wine

---

**Note:** Don't do this on an actively used server with insufficient ressources.. This slowed my Nagios server to a crawl! :)

---

*Sources*

- [Recommended Packages](http://wiki.winehq.org/Recommended_Packages)

Comment: +1 for the clear answer and the addition of the wine dependency installer. Did not know that one. Thank you SirCharlo.

Comment: Always glad to help!! :)