# Patch, compile and run Wine without installing

Tags: wine, compiling, install-from-source

I'm not familiar with compiling software from source.

I would like to test a patched version of Wine following [this procedure](http://wiki.winehq.org/USB).

I already have Wine installed and do not wish to modify it. I just want to have a secondary installation with a patched Wine.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: This is a different issue. That other question was for normal binary pre-compiled versions of wine. This is about compiling and using a patched version of wine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have Wine installed through package management, the `wine` binary is located in `/usr/bin`. Then just compile the patched Wine version.

You can [apply the patches](http://wiki.winehq.org/USB) and [compile Wine](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-719d19ccbd20c36445e065d0f46f80c2a301ce52). After the following two commands you can test Wine from the build directory:

```
./configure  
make
```

To install Wine (optional if you plan on running Wine from the build directory). If you run this command, the`wine` binary usually installs to `/usr/local/bin`. If you want to define the install location, you can use the configure parameter, for example: `./configure --prefix=/opt/wine157` which installs Wine to `/opt/wine157`

```
sudo make install
```

**Example** (on 64 bit system)**:**

```
wget http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/wine/source/1.5/wine-1.5.7.tar.bz2
tar -xvf wine-1.5.7.tar.bz2
cd wine-1.5.7
wget ftp://ftp.etersoft.ru/pub/people/amorozov/usb/1.5.7/0001-Add-support-of-native-Windows-drivers-for-USB-tokens.txt
wget ftp://ftp.etersoft.ru/pub/people/amorozov/usb/1.5.7/0002-Re-generate-some-files.txt
patch -p1 < 0001*.txt
patch -p1 < 0002*.txt
./configure --enable-win64
make
```

To show the Wine version from the build directory:

```
./wine64 --version
```

Installation:

```
sudo make install
```

Uninstall:

```
sudo make uninstall
```

**See:**

- [How to compile wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164888/how-to-compile-wine)
- [Installing Wine 1.5: configure: error: Cannot build a 32-bit program, you need to install 32-bit development libraries](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123273/installing-wine-1-5-configure-error-cannot-build-a-32-bit-program-you-need-t/)
- [Building 32-bit Wine on a 64-bit (x86-64) system](http://wiki.winehq.org/WineOn64bit)

Comment: i've encounter some issues when building, i.e. `error: ‘YYLEX’ undeclared (first use in this function)`, do you have any idea on how to fix this? (using bison 2.7.1, as suggested on forums, does not help...). thanks in advance